# Dojo browser compatibility check?

Tags: dojo

I am writing the Dojo applications. I want to provide the browser compatibility for Firefox 3.0+, IE 7+. Should I follow any specific techniques to get the browser compatiability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of supported browsers is here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.7.html.

One of the advantages of using a framework over plain javascript is that it deals with most compatibility issues for you.

Comment: The OP may notice that Firefox 3.0 is not supported. I doubt this will be a major issue, FF users have historically been quick to update, so there won't be many on 3.0; also, I suspect that this just means that FF3.0 is no longer tested, it is unlikely that one would encounter major compatibility issues on FF3.0. If you do encounter a problem when you test your site in an old browser, you will probably have to either ignore it, or patch it yourself.